# convert pdf to excel they show error cannot import name 'read_pdf' from 'tabula' (unknown location)`

Tags: python, web-scraping, tabula, tabula-py

When I convet pdf to excel they show these error `cannot import name 'read_pdf' from 'tabula' (unknown location)`

```
from tabula import read_pdf
data= tabula.read_pdf("CX.pdf", page="all")
print(data)
```

Comment: did you install tabula? `pip3 install tabula-py`?

Comment: yes I have have insall